# How Do I get the values of span tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How Do I get the value of a span tag and send it into my form to another page?

```
<span id="subtotal"></span>
```

I need to send the content of my span tag subtotal to another page, I would like to save it into a hidden field, but I found no way to do this..

I used this, but no success!

```
function getTotal() {
    return alert(document.getElementById('total').innerHTML);
}
```

Here goes the right function for those who need the answer! After I figured out the script ...

```
function getTotal() {
    //document.write(document.getElementById('total').innerHTML);
    var someValue = $(".total").text();
    alert("Value is "+someValue);
    //It cause to releoad the page and give me the parameter total          
    location.href="frmAdd.php?total=" + someValue; 
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

this will give you value

```
$("#subtotal").text();
```

Answer (score 8):

You could try the `.text()` method if you're using jQuery.

```
$("#subtotal").text();
```

Comment: just kidding , how come your answer is getting voted , i gave answer before yours....

Comment: @gov: I saw the both answers at the same moment. I found this answer more neat. More correct grammar and punctuation is used. It radiates more professionality.

Comment: @balusc no problem,I will do that way from next time.

Comment: @gov: I definitely had nothing to do with it, but yes, I always try to be grammatically correct as it does look more professional. =)

Answer (score 4):

The value of span is added to the input field of id="sub". you may use any events for assign values to hidden fields like click, change, submit, or you do as your logic .its an option.

```
$("#sub").val($("#subtotal").text());
<span id="subtotal"></span>
<input type="hidden" id="sub" >
```

Comment: It was already solved. Using id #subtotal .. anyway thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 2):

Should'nt you be having `subtotal` instead of `total` there?

```
function getTotal() {
    return alert(document.getElementById('subtotal').innerHTML);
}
```