# Use JQuery to select value of span in an li when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a foreach loop that displays a list of To-do items that it gets from a database I've created. Here's how I do that:

```
<ul class="todo-list">
    <?php foreach($todos as $todo) { ?>
        <li class="todo">
            <button class="delete-todo">&times;</button>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-checked">
            <span id="todo-text"><?php echo $todo; ?></span>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

I have an X button that I want to be able to delete the to-do item from that specific li from my database, but I'm having trouble getting the value of what is in the span tag.

Here's some sample JQuery that isn't working right:

```
$('.delete-todo').on('click', function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "deleteTodo.php",
        data: {"deleteTodo": $(".todo-text").next().text()},
        async: false,
        success: function(){

        },
        error: function() {

        }
    });
});
```

What is the best way of getting the value from the span tag? Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**

I've now switched it so that each todo has a unique id and I use the id to remove from the database. Thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Do I get the values of span tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280528/how-do-i-get-the-values-of-span-tags)

Comment: `id` should be unique

Comment: you should use an `id` in your database and not the actual text, what if you have two listings for `Get Milk`?

Comment: Great thanks for the help! I will accept the answer from @Pranav because it did answer my question, but you guys did give me an idea of how to better use id's to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` should be unique so use `class` instead

```
<ul class="todo-list">
    <?php foreach($todos as $todo) { ?>
        <li class="todo">
            <button class="delete-todo">&times;</button>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-checked">
            <span class="todo-text"><?php echo $todo; ?></span>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Span tag is sibling of button, so you can get it using `siblings()` selector

```
$(this).siblings('.todo-text').text()
```

```js
$('.delete-todo').on('click', function(e) {
  alert($(this).siblings('.todo-text').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="todo-list">
  <li class="todo">
    <button class="delete-todo">&times;</button>
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-checked">
    <span class="todo-text">dfdfdf</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply asking how to get the value of a span tag usiong jQuery, then this is definitely a duplicate question, as there are many solutions on stack overflow. Here is one of them:

[How Do I get the values of span tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280528/how-do-i-get-the-values-of-span-tags)

Now, i'll also tell you, what you could do to make sure you are getting the value from the CORRECT span tag is give each one of those span tags a unique id, so maybe change the id of each span tag to something like:

```
<span id=<?php echo '"todo-text-' . $todo .'"'; ?>>
```

This is a very dirty way of doing all of this in my opinion, but its a quick solution i guess. The snippet above also assumes your $todo variable is some sort of unique identifier.